# Sagt man "Ich stimme (dem/dir) zu" für "I agree with that"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, usage

> A: I think people in our city are spending too much nowadays.
>
> B: I agree with that.

---

> A: Ich glaube, dass Leute in unserer Stadt heutzutage zu viel ausgeben.
>
> B: _________

Es gibt [viele Übersetzungen](http://www.dict.cc/?s=i+agree) von "I agree with that", die hier passen: "Stimmt", "Ich bin einverstanden", "Du hast Recht", "Das sehe ich auch so", "Ich bin (ganz) deiner Meinung", usw.

Meine Frage ist, ob die scheinbar direktesten Übersetzungen auch passen würden.

> B: Ich stimme zu. // Ich stimme dem zu. // Ich stimme dir zu.

In der verlinkten Seite gibt es die Übersetzung "Ich stimme ... zu." Es ist aber nicht klar, wie genau man das benutzen kann.

Comment: Geht, klingt aber sehr formell, vor allem _Ich stimme dem zu_ und das pure _Ich stimme zu_. Mit _dir_ ist es etwas besser. Was übrigens nicht geht, ist _Ich bin einverstanden_. Einverstanden sein kann man mit einem Handlung, aber nicht mit einer Feststellung.

Comment: Das findet meine absolute Zustimmung ;-)

Comment: Im normalen Plauderton sagt man "Stimmt" oder "Ja, genau, finde ich auch, richtig". "Ich stimme dem zu"  klingt da schon ungewöhnlich.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, die Lücke in deinem Beispiel kann man mit allen drei Vorschlägen von dir füllen.

> A: Ich glaube, dass die Leute in unserer Stadt heutzutage zu viel (Geld) ausgeben.
>
> B: Ich stimme zu // Ich stimme dir zu // Ich stimme dem zu.

Allerdings – Unterpunkt Feinheiten der Sprache – wird das so kaum jemand sagen. Ein kurzes »Stimmt« wäre ausreichend; falls man das mehr als Meinung und weniger als Tatsache sieht, wäre »du hast Recht« und seine Verwandten besser.

---

> C: Ich glaube, dass die Erde eine Scheibe ist.
>
> D: Stimmt.

---

> E: Ich glaube, dass die Bundesregierung mehr für Hintertupflfing tun sollte.
>
> F: Da hast du Recht.

---

Es gibt allerdings des Öfteren Umfragen, die mit einer Aussage beginnen und folgendes fragen:

> Stimmen Sie der folgenden Aussage zu:
> »Der Bürgermeister von Hintertupflfing sollte Dialekt sprechen«
>
> O Stimme voll und ganz zu
>
> O Stimme überwiegend zu
>
> O Unentschieden
>
> O Lehne überwiegend ab
>
> O Lehne voll und ganz ab

Wobei man sich dann eine der Aussagen aussuchen und diese ankreuzen soll.